# How would a datetime(64) based numpy .resample('4H').mean() would look like?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any equivalent to the pandas `.resample('4H').mean()` functionality in numpy?

How would that look like?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're trying to take the mean of datetime objects?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question. So `.resample('4H').mean()` takes a pandas dataframe with a datetime like index and builds the average value of the columns of that data frame based on a time frame of 4 hours.

Comment: There is no built-in method for doing `groupby`-like operations in numpy. This sort of thing is what pandas was made for.